# Javascript: Calculating the sha-1 of an array of files using jsSHA

Tags: javascript, loops, filereader

I'm trying to obtain the sha-1 of 1559 files stored in an array.
For that purpose I've implemented the following routine using the library [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA):

```
           for (var i=0; i<_files.length; i++){
                (function(file, i) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function () {
                        try {
                            var raw_content = reader.result;
                            var actual_contents = raw_content.slice(raw_content.indexOf(',') + 1);
                            var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-1", "B64");
                            shaObj.update(actual_contents);
                            var file_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
                            console.log("File " + i + " hashed.");
                            file.file_hash = file_hash;
                        }
                        catch (e){
                            console.log("File " + i + "failed");
                            console.log(e);
                            console.log(file);
                        }
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                })(_files[i], i);
            }
```

My problem is that the loop only works well with the first 995 elements. Since element 996 it starts to fail returning me this error "Error: Invalid character in base-64 string"

I know that this issue it's possibly more related to the way that I'm trying to read the files than to the jsSHA library, but it someone could shed some light into my mind it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: is it always at 995th element? try process that element on its own, does it throw the same error? try removing or skipping that single element, does it still throw the error?

Comment: Where does Base64 enter the picture? Are the files expected to be Base64 encoded? Is the 996th file different? Is it empty?

Comment: @PA If I process the elements on their own, the hash function works fine.

Comment: @Thilo I have to upload those file to a storage provider which returns me asynchronously the sha-1 of those files that have been correctly upload. For that reason I need to calculate their sha-1 before sending them in order to check later the files that have been uploaded correctly. The 996th is not empty ant if I try to process it on its own the hash function works fine.

Comment: You are reading a thousand files at the same time. Maybe you run out of file handles or some other resource? Cannot you do this one at a time? Does it have to be asynchronous?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, I'm now thinking that it could be a matter of run out of file handles, but I'm not sure. What do you mean with doing it at a time? It hasn't to be asynchronous, in fact ideally it would be great if the process was synchronous (I've to wait until all the hashes are calculated before send them to the storage provider)

Comment: Is this in the browser or on Node.js ? On Node, there are synchronous API to read files. On the browser, you can use some Promise library to serialize execution.

Comment: @Thilo It's in the browser. I'm thinking about use this library https://github.com/kriskowal/q but I still don't know how to build the routine using it.